# import graphing in python

Tags: python, installation, pip, graphing

I have some troubles running the script from : https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/training/modules/introduction-to-data-for-machine-learning/5-exercise-normalize-data-predict-missing-values

in my own jupyter notebook

its the

```
import graphing
```

command in code block 3 that gives me errors:

```
AttributeError: module 'graphing' has no attribute 'histogram'
```

looked for problems like this, but without luck

Comment: Your import is not importing the correct thing. As part of looking into helping [this person get the script `graphing.py`](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/wget-not-working/16618/2?u=fomightez), I can confirm that the script `graphing.py` includes histogram so importing and running that code works without that error, or any error. I can add that the plot will display in either JupyterLab or the classic Jupyter Notebook interface (version 6 or earlier). The plot output didn't show properly (just blank space where it should be) in JupyterLab where I used `%pip install plotly` on the fly ...

Comment: <continued> , even after I restarted the kernel. But in an environment with Plotly installed first and then JupyterLab started up, the output showed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are taking a course on Microsoft Learn platform, since you cannot complete the course another platform of your choice, the solution is to select the "azureml_py38" kernel instead of the py38_default kernel that's giving an error.

I think it should work. I'm sure.

Answer (score -1):

Select another kernel in the upper part:

[image: Screenshot from some IDE]

Comment: As far as I know, Python doesn't come with anything like this. Are you trying to answer for a particular IDE?