# Error with the graphing library: "module 'graphing' has no attribute 'scatter_2D'"

Tags: python, data-science, graphing

Code:

```
import graphing

graphing.scatter_2D(dataset,    label_x="harness_size", 
                                label_y="boot_size",
                                trendline=lambda x: fitted_model.params[1] * x + fitted_model.params[0]
                              )
```

Why do I have this error:

```
module 'graphing' has no attribute 'scatter_2D'
```

It's from an Azure course.

Try to install the library, it's okay for this.

Comment: What is the `graphing` module? I guess this is a separate source file where you don‘t have the scatter_2D function defined.

Answer (score 0):

In the very first cell, there was a line:

!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-introduction-to-machine-learning/main/graphing.py

The Graphing.py file has a method defined as scatter_2D. If you are running this on your jupyter notebook, wget needs to be installed.
Edited: Or follow @wayne instructions from comment below

Comment: "wget needs to be installed". That isn't necessarily the only way to solve the problem. You don't need `wget` installed if you obtain the **correct** `graphing.py` file from [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-introduction-to-machine-learning/blob/main/graphing.py) and place that `.py` file in the directory with your notebook. You can even simply copy and paste from the github repo into a text file and save as `.py` on your system. Then move it to be in the same location on your system as the notebook. ...

Comment: <continued>Or actually acquire the entire repo by downloading it from GitHub (or use `git clone` if you know how). Then if you already have the files needed in the same location as the notebook to run, then you can skip the `wget` step. This has come up before, such as a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74289529/8508004), which points to advice [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/wget-not-working/16618/2?u=fomightez), a day before the original post here.